# create programmatically GStringExpression

Tags: groovy

I want to create `GStringExpression` that will represent this text line

```
"Exception: $all"
```

Its constructor can either have `verbatimText` or `verbatimText, strings[], values[]`

[GStringExpression](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/expr/GStringExpression.html#GStringExpression%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29)

How my text should be represented for `GStringExpression`?

For example this code

```
new GStringExpression("Exception:", [], [ new ConstantExpression("all") ])
```

results in `"Exception:"`. 
When I try to use `$all` inside `verbatimText` I am unable to compile it due to missing `all`

It seems it is using `verbatim` because the generated code looks like this,

[image]

while my `catchStatement` implementation looks like this

```
Parameter parameter = 
        new Parameter(ClassHelper.make(Exception.class), "all")
    ExpressionStatement returnStatement = new ExpressionStatement (
        new MethodCallExpression(
            new VariableExpression("this"),
            new ConstantExpression("println"),
            new ArgumentListExpression([
                new GStringExpression(null,
                    [ 
                        new ConstantExpression("Exception:")
                    ],
                    [ new VariableExpression("all") ]
                )
            ])
        )
    )
    new CatchStatement(parameter, returnStatement)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `verbatimText` is not used in the code generated from a `GStringExpression`. It's only here to have errors messages, or to "pretty dump" an AST.

The parameters `strings` and `values` are exactly the same as the parameters of the `GStringImpl` constructor. The code generated only push these properties into the stack, and call the constructor.

You can't transform a GString into an GStringExpression easily. In Groovy, this parsing is done with the antlr parser in the context of a script (and not only a GString). There is no methods with take a GString and create a `GroovyExpression`.

In your case, if the GString you want to create is "hello ${name}", then you have to pass as the strings parameters an array with a `ConstantExpression` with the value "hello ", and as the values parameters an array with a `VariableExpression` or a `FieldExpression`.

If what you want to do is only parsing a GString (and you are not creating an AST transformation) then you should probably use a `TemplateEngine`.

Comment: I am indeed trying to create transformation (I actually created but the only thing lacking is correct message inside `gstring`)

Comment: Afaik, `verbatim` is only used to dump the AST, not when groovy generate the bytecode. see this method : https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/classgen/AsmClassGenerator.java#L1808

Comment: In my case (as in example) it will display the content of `verbatim` as I stated before. Why it is doing it - I have no idea.

Comment: How do you see the code generated ? with a java decompiler, or the groovy console ?

Comment: I use groovyconsole. Though for some things I use decompiler too. but in that case - groovyconsole

Comment: That's why you see the verbatim property : the groovy console dump the AST, and the dump of a GStringExpression is only the verbatim property, but if you check the bytecode generated, you'll see it's not used, there is only a new GStringImpl